# First letter of string not appearing

Tags: bash, shell, curl, geolocation, location

I am making an IP Details script for my school, but I have encountered an error...

This is my code:

```
State=$(curl -s http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php | cut -c42-999 |
grep '</li>' | grep 'e : ' -B 1 | awk '{gsub("</li>", "");print}' |
sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | awk '{gsub("e :", "");print}')
echo $State
```

I am from Australia, New South Wales, but the script only says

```
 ew South Wales
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Part of the problem is that your output contains invisible characters, including carriage returns (which makes it go back to the beginning of the line, and then there's a space, which overwrites the "N"...). Try `echo "$State" | cat -vet` to see invisibles (carriage return will show as "^M").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `hxpipe` from the [W3C HTML-XML-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) (packaged for various operating systems, for example as `html-xml-utils` for Ubuntu). `hxpipe` turns HTML into something parseable with command line tools.

Example:

```
curl -s http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php | hxpipe | grep 'State/Province/'
-State/Province : Ontario
```

This is much simpler to process further, for example with awk to get everything after the colon:

```
$ curl -s http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php | hxpipe |
awk -F" *: *" '/State\/Province/ {print $NF}'
Ontario
```

This tells awk that fields are separated by a colon, surrounded by any number of spaces. The command itself selects lines that match `State/Province` (just like the grep command in the first example) and then prints the last field of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Given the output of that HTTP URI appears to be complex HTML with a line like:

```
<21 spaces><li>State/Province : Western Australia</li>
```

I can't actually see how that pipeline would even work given you appear to be cutting off the `"State/Province : "` (and possibly `W` (`N` in your case)) before you even search for the lines containing `"e :"`.

You would be far better off extracting the correct line first and then just grabbing the relevant text with a more adaptable command than `cut`.

Something like this should be a good start:

```
curl -s http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php
    | awk '$1 == "<li>State/Province" && $2 == ":" {
               $1 = "";
               $2 = "";
               gsub ("</li>", "");
               print
          }
          {}'
   | sed 's/^ *//'
```

The `awk` is a *single* command that will select lines where the first two columns match what you need, set those columns to empty strings, remove the `</li>` end tag and output the result.

The `sed` will then simply remove leading spaces due to the fact `awk` will still output spaces between the empty columns at the start.

That way, you don't need to worry about minor variations in line format if, for example, they start putting in more spaces or indenting with tabs rather than spaces. You'll still have to worry about *major* changes like changing the `"State/Province"` bit, but they should be far less likely.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is generally not the good tool for parsing HTML, but it can help in this simple case. Try this:

```
State=$(curl -s http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php | sed -n 's/.*<li>State\/Province : \([^<]*\)<\/li>.*/\1/p')
```

As the string `State/Province` only appears once in the page, this  one should work too:

```
State=$(curl -s http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php | sed -n 's/.*State\/Province : \([^<]*\)<.*/\1/p')
```